# Razuna (lucene) web service returns too much results

Tags: web-services, rest, lucene, dam

I am using a Razuna 1.7 web service to retrieve some assets but I've remarked that my web service call returns 2 results instead of one. Here is my web service call :

http://[ip]:[port]/razuna/global/api2/search.cfc?method=searchassets&api_key=EDEEC036D96647AFEE33EF01ECB06B82&searchfor=keywords:(%22TESTS%22)

Indeed, my filter on keywords should retrieve only one line, with keyword = TESTS whereas I've also received a second line with keyword = TEST.
It seems like there is a "fuzzy" option activated but, after having read the complete documentation, I still don't understand why my web service searching call is not a "exact" search.
Here is the official documentation :
http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/Search+and+Find+Assets#SearchandFindAssets-FuzzySearches

Does anyone have an idea ?
Is the "keyword" filter able to filter on another filter than "keyword" ?

Comment: The issue here is your field is being analyzed, so it creates two tokens "stackoverflow" and "tests". This is generally ideal for a full text field. For a field of unique identifiers or some such, you generally would want to index them without analysis. I'm unfamiliar with the service you are using, so I can't tell you how to do that. In a pinch, surrounding your query with quotes to perform a phrase search might do the job: `keywords:"STACKOVERFLOW TESTS"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've just edited my post. Indeed, in my actual case, the value is not including caracters like "_" or other, so, you can imagine that my filter value is "TESTS" and not "STACKOVERFLOW_TESTS" like initially introduced.
Do you have other ideas ?